# How do I close pop-up from third vendor

Tags: macos

I get this pop up when I start my computer. There's no option to close this. The blue-button just says 'try again'. Can someone please explain how I can deactive such messages completely?

[image]

Comment: You might get better help if you update your question to include the macOS version installed on your Mac.

Comment: Have you done what it suggests?